# Trigger inserting the same row twice

Tags: t-sql, triggers

First of all I am not an experienced programmer, so this question might seem a bit daft. I have written a trigger which is meant to insert a row to a second  table when a status field in the first table gets updated. The problem is that, it is inserting the same row twice and the second problem is if I update any filed in first table this trigger runs. Please help. this is what the trigger looks like

```
CREATE TRIGGER [c_CRM].[TR_TICKETLOG]
   ON [c_CRM].[T_SUPPORT_TICKETS]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 

  AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @TicketID int = (SELECT F_Ticket_ID FROM INSERTED)
DECLARE @StatusID int = (SELECT F_Ticket_Status_ID FROM INSERTED)
DECLARE @UpdateID int = (SELECT F_Ticket_Updated_By FROM INSERTED)
DECLARE @UserID int = (SELECT userID FROM FLEXVIEWS_USERS WHERE userID=@UpdateID)



IF(@StatusID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

DECLARE @message nvarchar(max) = (CASE @StatusID WHEN '1' THEN 'Ticket status set to Ticket Created' WHEN '2' THEN 'Ticket status set to Service in progress' WHEN '3' THEN 'Ticket status set to Awaiting client response' WHEN '4' THEN 'Ticket status set to Closed' WHEN '5' THEN 'Ticket status set to Pending' WHEN '6' THEN 'Ticket status set to Ticket Removed' ELSE ' ' END);
INSERT INTO c_CRM.T_TICKET_LOG (F_Ticket_Log_Ticket_ID, F_Ticket_Log_User_ID, F_Ticket_Log_Time, F_Ticket_Log_Message) VALUES (@TicketID, @UserID, GETDATE(), @message);
UPDATE T_SUPPORT_TICKETS SET F_Ticket_Updated_On = GETDATE() WHERE F_Ticket_ID = @TicketID;
END

ELSE
        UPDATE c_CRM.T_TICKET_LOG
        SET F_Ticket_Log_Message = NULL
        WHERE F_Ticket_Log_Ticket_ID = @TicketID;
END
```

Comment: Change the trigger definition to CREATE TRIGGER [c_CRM].[TR_TICKETLOG]
   ON [c_CRM].[T_SUPPORT_TICKETS]
   AFTER INSERT (Remove Update if not require)

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain *multiple* (or *no*) rows.

Comment: Update is required , but when I tried with Insert alone it did return just 1 row which is great, but I need it to work for Update.

Comment: The inserted table for status field will always have a value because it is set to a default value, infact there is never a condition when its null.

Comment: If your second comment was a response to mine, I think you're missing what I was saying. `inserted` can contain, say, 10 rows. This line: `DECLARE @StatusID int = (SELECT F_Ticket_Status_ID FROM INSERTED)` (and the others like it) is going to go wrong because it's attempting to return 10 values on the right hand side, but on the left hand side you have a scalar variable. That variable cannot contain 10 different values. You need to write set-based statements that recognise that `inserted` can contain multiple rows.